# clear window in bot v4

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I want to clear bot window once user logged out. I used below code in js

```
//used class to remove all elements

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("wc-message-wrapper"))
     .forEach(element => element.remove());
```

and it worked but after this I am unable to render chat again without refreshing the page. I want to send welcome message automatically after clearing window.

Comment: Why not refresh the entire web page?  I find that removes everything

Comment: That's not a standard practice because it will refresh webpage activities also in which bot is ingesṯed.

Comment: It's standard practice for a webchat bot whose page only consists of a bot

Comment: I got the solution